# xhtml2pdf child elements show border of parent elements

Tags: python, css, xhtml2pdf

Hoping someone may have solved this problem. Haven't seen anyone with it on Google.

I'm using xhtml2pdf in Python, trying to generate a simple document with a header, footer and my content is blocks of text with titles. I'd like to have a border around each piece of content but instead I get borders around each child element instead.

Here's my HTML

```css
@page {
  size: letter;
  border: 0;
  @frame header_frame {
    -pdf-frame-content: header;
    border: 0pt solid white;
    left: .75in;
    width: 7in;
    top: .5in;
    height: 1.5in;
  }
  @frame content_frame {
    border: 0pt solid white;
    left: .75in;
    width: 7in;
    top: 1.5in;
    height: 7.5in;
  }
  @frame footer_frame {
    -pdf-frame-content: footer;
    border: 0pt solid white;
    left: .75in;
    width: 7in;
    top: 9.5in;
    height: 1in;
  }
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 5pt;
}

.desc {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST TEST TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="title">TITLE OF ARTICLE</div>
    <span>TEST 2</span>
    <div>TEST 3</div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Test4</td>
        <td>Test 5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm just running the `xhtml2pdf` command line tool at the moment so there's no python to show. One thing I did notice when I run it in debug mode it shows "xhtml = false" even though I have an XHTML DTD. I'm not sure if this would make a difference.

Here's what I see in the browser and roughly what I expect the pdf to look like (ignoring the footer location of course):

[image: expected output]

Instead I get:

[image]

**EDIT**: I figured out that xhtml is an option to pass but passing it fails unless one has an old version of html5lib installed. Looks like the answer to my question is this library is not being actively maintained and I need to find a new solution :-/

Comment: Hi @Cfreak , What elements are taken for xhtml2pdf? 
Normal div and inline stlyes won't be sufficient so that it reflects the same onto as pdf?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK I'm not completely sure I understand your question but what I discovered is the xhtml2pdf project appears to be dead and to make it work you need an old version of the underlying library. I solved my problem using a different tool called weasyprint instead: http://weasyprint.org/